# Pom/Project Properties via Eclipse maven2

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, m2eclipse

I packaging my java project with maven, using the M2 Plug in Eclipse

I need to provide a value for the following pom property (module_version), for local packaging this will have a value like “local-SNAPSHOT”

```
  <groupId>com.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>server</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>${module_version}</version>
```

Run config env variables don't seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you need to specify the property `module_version` via the command line. In that case you can do so by typing:

```
$> mvn -Dmodule_version=local-SNAPSHOT package
```

Another way is to take it from the environment assuming you have exported the enviromnemt varialble by typing

```
$>export module_version=local-SNAPSHOT
```

An in your pom you can use:

```
  <groupId>com.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>server</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>${env.module_version}</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're getting at, but if this is your base config file you should specify the version of your application within the `<version>`-tags. This will allow you to use that version to extract any subprojects from your local repo, as well as using the `${project.version`} variable for filtering.

See [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2005/jw-1205-maven.html) for an example of a base pom file.